# Figuring out how to build this form using bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-5

**Dropdown form to build**

[image: Dropdown form to build]

I want to build a form for updating team scores based on kills, I am not sure how to split the form into 2 sections for input as shown, I am only using bootstrap for styling, any guides or help provided is much appreciated.

i tried to split the form into 2 but it didnt work out

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group row mx-auto" style="color: black;">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 text-center mb-3 mb-md-0">
      <select class="team_name form-control" placeholder="Teams" style="height: 30px;">
        <option value="team1">Team 1</option>
        <option value="team2">Team 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 text-center">
      <input type="number" name="team_kill" placeholder="Kills" class="form-control" style="height: 30px; width: 70px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add your code which have you try. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have just added the code for the form that I have produced so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it use with [counter-increment](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.php) and [column-count](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.php) css.

CSS

```
.myform{column-count: 2; column-gap: 30px;}
.myform li{counter-increment: step-counter; }
```

HTML

```
<ol class="myform">
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
    <li>Your form-group</li>
</ol>
```